# Java - Spring Data JPA - concurrency issue

Tags: java, sql-server, multithreading, concurrency

I have a serious issue related to concurrency that I tracked down to this method:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)
void updateRecords(Long userId) {
    List<Record> currentRecordsList = recordsDao.getByUserId(userId);   // sometimes exception occurs here
    List<Long> listToRemove = ...
    // processing...

    if (!listToRemove.isEmpty()) {
        recordsDao.deleteRecords(userId, listToRemove);
    }
    // processing...

    List<Record> listToAdd = new ArrayList<>();
    for (...) {
        // create new records...
        listToAdd.add(record);
    }

    if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(listToAdd)) {
        recordsDao.save(listToAdd);     // and sometimes exception occurs here
        recordsDao.flush();
    }
}
```

When executed synchronously it works good. But when it's executed concurrently from different threads and some threads require update (i.e. `listToAdd` is not empty) then it fails with the following exceptions:

```
Unexpected error occurred invoking async method 'public void updateRecords(java.lang.Long)'
...
org.springframework.dao.CannotAcquireLockException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: could not execute statement
...
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: could not execute statement
...
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Transaction (Process ID 65) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim.
```

I wrote a test case that makes a few REST calls simultaneously so now I can easily reproduce this issue. But I'm out of ideas on how to fix it... Can you help me?

Comment: Does it occur with different `userIds` or when you're using the same `userId` to execute concurrently? Can a record have multiple users, or is each record tied to a single user?

Comment: So you are trying to update and delete the same records concurrently This results in a dead lock. If you need to access the same records you must synchronize the access which means that this method is not a good candidate for parallel execution. You have to rethink your design.

Comment: @Kayaman User to Record relation is One-To-Many. I'm inclined to think that it occurs when this method is invoked 3-4 times in parallel for the same `userId`

Comment: So everything is working correctly then. Now you need to decide what's the correct course of action when that happens. Do you retry the operation? Do you indicate to the initiator of the operation that things may have changed in the database, and you need to re-initiate your request? It all depends on what you're trying to do.

Comment: Hmm... @Kayaman, how do you think - Can I organize a pool of locks (one lock per user) to guard this method? So when this method is called for the first time, it runs update / delete processing. And if it's called again (while the first invocation is still running) the subsequent invocation just waits for the first invocation to finish, and then both of them return updated data (I'll call `recordsDao.getByUserId(userId)` after this method).

Comment: Will the second call still be valid after the first one is done? If so, then yes you can lock based on the `userId`. An easy way is to use Guava's [Striped lock](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Striped.html). If you're not using Guava you'll need to come up with your own solution, but I wouldn't recommend that. Concurrency is hard to get right, and you need to know what you're doing.

Comment: @Kayaman yes, the data in `Record` table is not changed very often. There's just a need to collect data from other tables across database on the first invocation in order to return data faster on subsequent invocations. But when executed concurrently and update happens (i.e. new record(s) found) this solution fails... I am not experienced user of Guava but I like this library, and I'll take a look at Striped lock. Thank you for your advice!